# InstallScheme Script for dynamic rows Magento 2

Tags: magento2, install-script, dynamic-rows, database-schema

I have created dynamic rows on product creation form. I have to save their value in custom table and retrieve as a dropdown on frontend product detail page w.r.t product ID.
I am aware of the event

> catalog_product_save_after

All I want to know is how to save these values into table (the installschema script) and get values on frontend.
 My dynamic rows are in screen shot for more clear understanding.

[image]